# Asymptotic distribution of the extreme, standardized order statistics of uniform distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Let $\{U_{k, n}\}_{k=1}^n$, denote the order statistics of a sample of $n$ iid uniform $[0, 1]$ variates.

Note that, marginally $U_{k, n}$ is distributed $\mathrm{Beta}(k, n+1 -k)$.
Therefore, let us denote the corresponding mean and variance parameters, respectively, by
$$
\mu_{k, n} = \frac{k}{n+1} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \sigma^2_{k,n} = \frac{k (n+1 - k)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}. 
$$
Let us define the extreme values
$$
Y_n = \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{U_{k, n} - \mu_{k, n}}{\sigma_{k, n}} 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
Z_n = \min_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{U_{k, n} - \mu_{k, n}}{\sigma_{k, n}} 
$$
Is it possible to derive the asymptotic distributions of $Y_n$ and  $Z_n$,marginally, as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Do you want the asymptotic joint distribution of $Y_n, Z_n$, or the asymptotic distribution of $Y_n$ and the asymptotic distribution of $Z_n$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis marginal asymptotic distributions. So essentially, $F_Y(y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n \leq y)$ and $F_Z(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(Z_n \leq z)$.